# I want to get the one result

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to get a percentage calculation im having an error.

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "100"
> LINE 1: SELECT dispute_lost , ROUND(COUNT() 100/SUM(COUNT (*)) OVER(...
>                                            ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 37
> ```

Query:

```
SELECT dispute_lost , ROUND(COUNT() 100/SUM(COUNT (*)) OVER(),2) AS Percentage_lost
FROM yellevate_invoices
GROUP BY dispute_lost;
```

Comment: I think you wanted to do `*100`, to get from fractions to percentages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to COUNT something, you cannot COUNT nothing. COUNT() is not accepted. The syntax for COUNT agergate is :

```
COUNT( [ { DISTINCT | ALL } ] <expression>)
<expression ::= { * | <scalar_expression> }
```